# Can multiple webpages be implemented using a single Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

Can multiple webpages be implemented using an single Flask app by writing inner methods and routing them properly?

```
from flask import Flask,request,redirect
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def admin_login():
    return render_template('admin_login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    un = request.form['un']
    pwd = request.form['pwd']
    print un,pwd

    @app.route("/login")
    def adminPage1():
        return render_template('adminPage1.html')

    @app.route("/login/addnew")
    def addnew():
        return render_template('adminPage2.html')
    @app.route("/login/updatestatus")
    def updatestatus():
        return render_template('adminPage3.html')
```

`admin_login.html`:

```html
<form action="{{url_for('login')}}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div align="left">
            <p><a href="home.html"><strong>Return to home page</strong></a></p>
        </div>
        <p><strong>Username:</strong><input type="text" name="un" ></p>
        <p><strong>Password:</strong><input type="password" name="pwd"></p>
        <h4>If you have forgot your password,kindly enter your username and click on forgot password</h4>
        <p><a href="forgotpassword.html">forgot Password?</a></p>
        <p><input type="reset"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

`adminPage1.html`:

```html
<form action="{{url_for('addnew')}}" method="post">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add New" onclick="location.href='adminPage2.html'"></p>
</form>
<form action="{{url_for('updatestatus')}}" method="post">
    <p><input type="submit" value="Update Status" onclick="location.href='adminPage3.html'"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Defining a route inside another route means the inner route won't be available until the outer route is accessed (either by a request for the URL or by calling the endpoint directly). If your goal is to have a shared prefix on URLs, I suggest taking a look at [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to implement is a prefix for your routes. Try using a blueprint:

In your view (login.py) define a blueprint:

```
blueprint = Blueprint('login', __name__, url_prefix='/login')
```

Above the view you then define a route for this blueprint like you would on the application:

```
@blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_login():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login
    return render_template('admin_login.html')

@blueprint.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login/login
    return  render_template('adminPage1.html')

@blueprint.route('/addnew/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adminPage1():
    # Located at https://yourdomain.com/login/addnew
    return  render_template('adminPage1.html')
```

Then you can import this blueprint in your `__init__.py`:

```
from application.login import blueprint

application =- Flask(__name__)
application.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

For more information about blueprints, see the documentation of Flask on [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/#registering-blueprints)

Comment: If I use blueprint can I implement the same code of myne

Comment: Yes, i updated my post to show you how you could do that

Comment: In the HTML code of adminPage1.HTML should I change action=  {{url_for('addnew')}} to action={{url_for('login/addnew')}} or it directly routes to it.

Comment: Use `url_for('login.adminPage1')` to get the route. Mind the synthax (module)(dot)(method).